# 2 приложения, 2 домена. что писать в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, yii

Будет два приложения host/www/site1 и host/www/site2.
Yii будет лежать в host/www/framework

В vhost.conf оба домена(site1.ru, site2.ru) будут ссылаться на host/www

Стоит заметить, что сайты не громоздкие, а количество контроллеров колеблется от 5 до 8 и они разные(site1/action1, site1/action2, ... site2/action10, site2/action11). Поэтому, не долго думая, планирую в htaccess раскидывать по приложениям приблизительно так.

```
RewriteRule ^action1$             /site1/index.php?r=action1[L]
RewriteRule ^action2$            /site1/index.php?r=action2[L]
...
RewriteRule ^action10$            /site2/index.php?r=action10[L]
RewriteRule ^action11$            /site2/index.php?r=action11[L] 
...
```

ИЛИ

я сильно загоняюсь и проще прописать разные пути в vhost.conf?

Какой способ предпочтительней и какие возможные подводные камни могут ожидать?

Comment: очень сильно загоняетесь, во первых [UrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.url)

а во вторых - [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) вам нужен HTTP_HOST

Comment: @eicto если не сложно, то пара примеров очень помогут в понимании.